# How to pass Binding variable to an ObservableObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a binding variable that I need to pass to an ObservableObject in swiftUI.

Let's say I have this code:

```
struct MYView: View {

    @ObservedObject var fetch = Fetch()
    
    @Binding var IDTxt: Int
      
    var body: some View{
    
    //some code here

    }

}
```

Now I want to pass the `IDTxt` value to this:

```
public class Fetch: ObservableObject {

   
   //I need to pass the Binding variable here. something like this?
   @Binding var IDTxt: Int
    
    init(){
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {

    //So I can use it here like this:

    let url = URL(string: "http://someurl.com/\(IDTxt)")

    }
```

Could someone please advice on the above?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to pass the Binding value. But you can pass direct value.

```
public class Fetch: ObservableObject {
    
    var IDTxt: Int
    
    init(id: Int){
        self.IDTxt = id
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        
        //So I can use it here like this:
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://someurl.com/\(IDTxt)")
        
    }
}

struct MYView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var fetch: Fetch
    
    @Binding var IDTxt: Int
    
    init(IDTxt: Binding<Int>) {
        self._IDTxt = IDTxt
        self.fetch = Fetch(id: IDTxt.wrappedValue)
    }
    
    var body: some View{
        
        //some code here
        Color.red
        
    }
}
```

If you want to observe IDTxt text then use `@Published` in class.

```
public class Fetch: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var IDTxt: Int
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Type 'Fetch.Type' cannot conform to 'ObservableObject'

Comment: @roozfar compile fine in my system. where you get this error?

Comment: here: @ObservedObject var fetch: Fetch

Comment: Can you try to add this code to a new project? The issue might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for `Binding`s if the property you are trying to inject into `Fetch` is coming from a parent view. You can simply inject the value in the init.

Also, if you are creating an `ObservableObject` inside a `View`, you need to declare it as `@StateObject`. `@ObservedObject` should only be used when injecting the object into the view.

```
public class Fetch: ObservableObject {
    
    init(id: Int) {
        load(id: id)
    }
    
    func load(id: Int) {
        let url = URL(string: "http://someurl.com/\(id)")

    }


struct MYView: View {

    @StateObject private var fetch: Fetch

    init(id: Int) {
        self._fetch = StateObject(wrappedValue: Fetch(id: id))
    }
      
    var body: some View{
        EmptyView()
    }

}
```

Comment: @roozfar one of the base building blocks of `Combine`. When you create a `Subscription`, an `AnyCancellable` is returned and the subscription is only kept alive as long as you hold a reference to the `AnyCancellable` (or until you manually call `cancel`).

Comment: Your code seems to be doing the opposite of what I'm trying to do! Are you passing the IDTxt to MyView?

Comment: @roozfar you are trying to call `load` based on `idTxt` coming from the view, right? That's exactly what my code is doing. `idText` is updated with the value the user inputs to a `TextField` and `Fetch` calls load with that value.

Comment: Sorry, the IDTxt is already a variable passed onto my MYView from another View. now I need to use it inside the Fetch: ObservableObject {... there's no TextInput.

Comment: @roozfar updated my answer to match your requirements

Comment: getting this error: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Comment: on this line:     init(id: Int) {
        self._fetch = StateObject(wrappedValue: Fetch(id: id))
    }

Comment: @roozfar that piece of code compiles just fine, so you must have some other properties on your view that you aren't initialising. If you copy the code from my answer, it will compile